# Laravel email verification sent with HTML tags

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

Im trying to send an email but when the email is received it with its html tags

```
 <tr> <td class="header"> <a href="http://localhost"> TikTak</a> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <table 
class="footer" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> <tr> <td class="content- 
cell" align="center"> &lt;p&gt;ÃÂ© 2019 ÃÂªÃÂÃÂ§ÃÂÃÂ ÃÂ­ÃÂÃÂÃÂ 
ÃÂ¨ÃÂ±ÃÂ§ÃÂ Rabter ÃÂÃÂ­ÃÂÃÂÃÂ¸ ÃÂÃÂ ÃÂ¨ÃÂ§ÃÂ´ÃÂ¯&lt;/p&gt; </td> </tr> 
</table> </td> </tr>
```

I do have  `\Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');` in my `Appserviceprovider` and also changed `{{}}` in markdown folder to `{!! !!}` and also in the html folder but unfortunately it did NOT fix it

It was working properly and suddently its output turned into this mess

Thanks for anyhelp

Comment: Please post the code of your view. We can not guess what your code is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `<meta charset="utf-8">` tage in you email template.

Comment: did that already, its in the layout of my email which then I extend into the page